# background-position does not work in IE8 when the selector includes 2 clases

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I have this simple CSS code that does not work in IE8

```
.quicklinks .glyphicon {
    background: url("/images/scss-images/glyphicon-sprite-ie8.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0;
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
    display: block;
}

.glyphicon-chevron-up {
    background-position: -77px -53px;
 }
```

HTML

```
<div class="quicklinks">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>
</div>
```

When I remove the ".quicklinks" class from the selector it works fine, but for some other reasons I need to be specific assiging the background only for the ".glyphicon" inside of ".quicklinks".

Someone knows a fix to this? to make it work in IE8?

Comment: Works fine here with the two classes in IE8. http://fiddle.jshell.net/MrLister/yz5uqhka/1/show/

Comment: I tried your fiddle in a VM with IE8 and it does not work there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Response for people with this same issue.

Even than the background-position: -77px -53px; was applied as last rule just placing the !important made it work